# Imperative method finishing after next line of imperative method call LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I am calling method in js like

```
this.myMethod();
var = true;
```

The method is defined else where in js file like

```
myMethod()
{
//calling Apex Method
}
```

but the issue is the `var = true` gets executed before completion of myMethod(). How can i make sure that next line executes only after execution of called method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apex methods are called asynchronously. You need to [wait](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for them to finish if that's your intent:

```
async method1() {
  await this.myMethod();
  this.someVar = true;
}

async myMethod() {
  return myApexMethod({params})
}
```